# Trying to save data in an Association table in many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm new with SQLAlchemy. I have a many-to-many relationship in my models between Player-Match.

```
class PlayerMatch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player_match'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    player_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("player.id")) 
    match_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("match.id")) 
    team: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(1))
    pichichi: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default='f', default=False)
        
    player: Mapped["Player"] = relationship(back_populates="matches")
    match: Mapped["Match"] = relationship(back_populates="players")

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = "player"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    firstname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    telephone: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(30))
    country_code: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(3))
    photo: Mapped[Optional[bytes]] = mapped_column(LargeBinary())
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default='t', default=True)
    match_mvp: Mapped["Match"] = relationship(back_populates="mvp")
    
    matches: Mapped[Optional[List["PlayerMatch"]]] = relationship(back_populates="player", lazy='selectin')
    

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    datetime: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now())
    teamA_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    teamB_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    teamA_score: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(default=0)
    teamB_score: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(default=0)
    location_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("location.id")) 
    location: Mapped["Location"] = relationship(back_populates="matches")
    mvp_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("player.id")) 
    mvp: Mapped[Optional["Player"]] = relationship(back_populates="match_mvp", lazy='selectin')
    #pichichis: Mapped[Optional[List["Player"]]] = relationship(secondary="player_match")
    players: Mapped[Optional[List["PlayerMatch"]]] = relationship(back_populates="match", lazy='selectin')
```

However, when I try to save a object from the association table (in this case PlayerMatch), I get that the match_id is always null.

```
@router.put('/{id}')
async def update_match(id: int, matchSchema: Match, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)) -> JSONResponse:
    async with session.begin():
        try:
            stmt = select(models.Match).filter_by(id=id)
            result = await session.execute(stmt)
            match = result.scalars().one()
            match.datetime = matchSchema.datetime
            match.teamA_name = matchSchema.teamA_name
            match.teamA_score = matchSchema.teamA_score
            match.teamB_name = matchSchema.teamB_name
            match.teamB_score = matchSchema.teamB_score
            if not matchSchema.mvp:
                match.mvp = None
            else:
                stmt = select(models.Player).filter_by(id=matchSchema.mvp)
                result = await session.execute(stmt)
                player = result.scalars().one()
                match.mvp = player
            # players
            match.players = []
            teamA = []
            if matchSchema.teamA_players:
                for player_id in matchSchema.teamA_players:
                    p = models.PlayerMatch(team='A', player_id=player_id, match_id=match.id)
                    teamA.append(p)
            teamB = []
            if matchSchema.teamA_players:
                for player_id in matchSchema.teamA_players:
                    p = models.PlayerMatch(team='B', player_id=player_id, match_id=match.id)
                    teamB.append(p)
            match.players = teamA + teamB
            await session.commit()
            return jsonable_encoder(match)
        except NoResultFound as ex:
            return JSONResponse({'ok': False, 'error': str(ex)}, status_code=404)
```

I get this error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError'>: null value in column "match_id" of relation "player_match" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, null, A, f).
[SQL: UPDATE player_match SET match_id=$1::INTEGER WHERE player_match.id = $2::INTEGER]
[parameters: [(None, 1), (None, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4)]]
```

but I do fill it correctly:

```
p = models.PlayerMatch(team='A', player_id=player_id, match_id=match.id)
```

Where is it going wrong?

Thanks